# How to get PSQL function to return VARCHAR[] and process it in JDBC?

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jdbc, stored-functions

I am writing a function that removes all the acts for a given Gig

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION removeAllActsFromGig(gGigId INTEGER) RETURNS VARCHAR[]`

It should return all the customer names that are affected by this cancellation and set the cost of their ticket to 0.

There is a ticket table with fields gigID, CustomerName and cost.

I have declared a VARCHAR array, a, and am trying to insert the result of the below query into the array and return it.

`a VARCHAR[]`

`UPDATE ticket SET Cost = 0 WHERE gigID = gGigID RETURNING CustomerName INTO a;`

On a processing level, in Java, I would like to cast the array returned as an array of Strings. There is some documentation on this e.g: [Using Array Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html)

Here's the corresponding JDBC code:

```
removeAllActsFromGig = conn.prepareCall("{? = call removeAllActsFromGig(?) }");
removeAllActsFromGig.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
removeAllActsFromGig.setInt(2, gigID);     
removeAllActsFromGig.execute();
String[] result = (String[])removeAllActsFromGig.getArray(1);
```

However, upon attempting to cast the result I am getting the error

`java.sql.Array cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]`

Anyone have any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the Java code that results in the error.

Comment: I would guess that a Java driver would be likely to return (say with `CallableStatement`) a `ResultSet` for your returned array. You would have to create an array on the Java side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getArray()` returns a `java.sql.Array`, not a Java array. You must call `getArray()` on *that* instance. The result of that can be cast to a Java array

```
java.sql.Array array = removeAllActsFromGig.getArray(1);
String[] result = (String[])array.getArray();
```

---

You also don't need a CallableStatement to use a Postgres function. A good old PreparedStatement and `executeQuery()` will work just fine

```java
PreparedStatement removeAllActsFromGig = 
        conn.prepareStatement("select removeAllActsFromGig(?)");

removeAllActsFromGig.setInt(1, gigID);     
ResultSet rs = removeAllActsFromGig.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
   Array array = rs.getArray(1);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Whats the benefit of using a prepared statement as opposed to a callable statement?